# Selecting every other node uing XPATH

Tags: xpath

Given an arbitrary amount nodes to select:

```
<root>
  <foo>1</foo>
  <foo>2</foo>
  <foo>3</foo>
  <foo>4</foo>
  <!-- ... -->
<root>
```

How do I select every other foo so that I get foo[1], foo[3], ... ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try

```
/root/foo[position() mod 2 = 1]
```

No idea if it will work right, might need 0. I forget if position starts at 0 or 1

Comment: that is more likely to be on the right track.  I was looking at the reference http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_operators.asp here and trying to see that.  Let us know when you've found the right answer!

Answer (score 0):

position() returns a number that indicates the position of an element relative to other child elements.
The mod function returns the „rest“ of a division:
5 mod 2 = 1;   6 mod 2 = 0;   9 mod 2 = 1;   10 mod 2 = 0;

also see: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/modulo