# VB.net XML Remove Every Second Element by Tag Name

Tags: xml, vb.net

I am working with the following XML example:

```
<order>
    <name></name>
    <etc></etc>
    <etc></etc>
    <components>
        <component>
            <sub></sub>
        </component>
        <component>
            <sub></sub>
        </component>
        <component>
            <sub></sub>
        </component>
        <component>
            <sub></sub>
        </component>
    </components>
</order>
```

I'm trying to select and remove every second `<component>` and it's `sub`s in vb.net.

Below is what I've got so far:

```vb
'make xmldocument object to hold xml string'
Dim XMLDoc As New XMLDocument()
XMLDoc.LoadXML(strXMLContent)
'get all elements named component'
Dim componentList As XmlNodeList = XMLDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Component")
Dim c As Integer
Dim i As Integer = 1
'for every component element add i to itself to only get seconds'
'and if on a second element, remove it and all sub elements inside it'
For c = 0 To componentList.Count - 1
    i += i
    If i > 2 Then
        componentList(c).ParentNode.RemoveChild(componentList(c))
    End If
Next c
'output to a string to see results'
x &= XMLDoc.DocumentElement.OuterXml
```

The problem I'm having is that I get "`Object reference not set to an instance of an object`" when I run this, on the line where the actual `RemoveChild()` is called.

Comment: Can you describe the issue you are having? It's not clear from your question what is wrong.

Comment: Right now I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when I run this. I'm not sure what logic I should be using on the line where I remove a child.

Comment: You should include any information directly in the question, as some people might miss the comments. I've edited the question for you this time. This isn't my area of expertise, I'm just reviewing your question (all first-time questions are reviewed) so now it appears to be a good question I'll leave it to the experts to answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Function GetRidOfEveryOtherComponent(ByVal strXML As String) As String
    'make xmldocument object to hold xml string'
    Dim XMLDoc As New XmlDocument()
    XMLDoc.LoadXml(strXML)
    'get every other component item
    Dim componentList As XmlNodeList = XMLDoc.SelectNodes("order/components/component[position() mod 2 = 1]")
    For c As Integer = 0 To componentList.Count - 1
        componentList(c).ParentNode.RemoveChild(componentList(c))
    Next c
    'output to a string to see results'
    Return XMLDoc.DocumentElement.OuterXml
End Function
```

That cool mod function is courtesy of Paul, here: [Selecting every other node uing XPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260282/selecting-every-other-node-uing-xpath)

Comment: My actual full path in my code uses "soap:Envelope/soap:Body/SubmitOrder/Order/Components/Component[position() mod 2 = 1]" which gives this error - System.Xml.XPath.XPathException: Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function - I understand I need to add a namespace, but for what part?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was with two things, how I was adding my `i` integer, as well as the if statement structure, when combined, made it so the `componentList(c)` I was removing, really was null. Below is my working fix.

```
'make xmldocument object to hold xml string'
 Dim XMLDoc As New XMLDocument()
 XMLDoc.LoadXML(strXMLContent)
'get all elements named component'
 Dim componentList As XmlNodeList = XMLDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Component")
 Dim c As Integer
 Dim i As Integer = 0
'for every "Component" element add 1 to i - remove every second by checking if i is modular'
 For c = 0 To componentList.Count - 1
     i += 1
     If Not i Mod 2 Then
         componentList(c).ParentNode.RemoveChild(componentList(c))
     End If
 Next c
'output to a string to see results'
 x &= XMLDoc.DocumentElement.OuterXml
```